# How to change the resolution of the login window?

Tags: login-screen

I've installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 gnome and My device resolution is 1600x900. But the login screen resolution seems like 1024x768. I've tried changing the resolution from the settings manger but the login screen resolution still remains the same. What should I do?

Comment: Provide info on your graphics card, and on whether you run Xorg or Wayland. You can see both in the "About" pane in settings. I suspect nVidia and Xorg because this should work properly on Wayland. You could try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/631368/set-resolution-for-gdm-on-15-04